# How Do I Select Multiple Nodes At A Time From Treeview Control Using C# And Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Here are the code for creating the tree structure from the database in the treeview control of windows forms and my table contains `Id`, `Title`, `Pid`, `DescId` attributes. and yes i am calling this method from inside a button click event like this only:- `CreateTree(null, 0);`

Property of treeview i already made `checkboxes==true` so by this when tree populate they came together with checkbox and nodes of the treeview.

```
    //Create the tree from the database
    private void CreateTree(TreeNode n, int hdrID)
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=D:\DNP\Opening ppt\Opening ppt\Builder.mdf;MultipleActiveResultSets = True;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id,Title FROM Presentation WHERE Pid=" + hdrID, con);
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            TreeNode t = new TreeNode(rdr["Title"].ToString());
            CreateTree(t, Convert.ToInt16(rdr["Id"].ToString()));
            if (n == null)
            {
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(t);
                //t.ImageIndex = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                n.Nodes.Add(t);
            }
        }
        rdr.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void treeView1_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Action != TreeViewAction.Unknown)
            {
                 if (busy) return;
                busy = true;
                try
                {
                    TreeNode _node = e.Node;

                    checkNodes(e.Node, e.Node.Checked);
                    if (e.Node.Checked)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(e.Node.Text);
                    }
                }


                finally
                {
                    busy = false;
                }
            }

        }
```

`private void checkNodes(TreeNode node, bool check)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode child in node.Nodes)
            {
                if (child.Checked == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(child.Text);
                } 
                //MessageBox.Show(child.Text);
                checkNodes(child, check);
            }
        }`

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked several times, and the answer is: it's possible, but not trivial.

Native `TreeView` control does not allow multiple selection, but you could derive a subclass from it and override some behaviors to make it work.

Personally I don't recommend this, since it's not easy to get it right. I suggest you search some controls that may do the job.

Please check [this site](http://www.arstdesign.com/articles/treeviewms.html), it gives a `TreeView` control that allows multiple selection, and technical details as well :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [nevets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25499409/487356) - it's a real pain to do multiple selection with the `TreeView` control.

In my own projects I use [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) instead. I use it as a replacement for the WinForm `ListView` and `TreeView` controls. It supports multiple selection, tree views with multiple columns, and much more!

Comment: can you help me out ? How you use the objectListView instead of treeview controls. i am eager to learn it . i f its possible can you send some poc regarding this topic to nitesh943@gmail.com .

Comment: A code example alone won't help you much. The way you fill the `ObjectListView` with data is very different from the traditional `ListView` and `TreeView`. You first need to understand this new approach. Once you understand that, the `ObjectListView` is easy to use. The author of the library did a great job explaining it. Start reading [here](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/gettingStarted.html). How to use the `TreeListView` (which is what you need) is explained [here](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#how-do-i-use-a-treelistview).

Comment: There is also an example project included with the `ObjectListView` sources, and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16009/A-Much-Easier-to-Use-ListView) is a good article on CodeProject which explains `ObjectListView` in detail.