# how to select multiple nodes (if it contains particular text) in a treeview in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a treeview like below,

```
tables
--table1
  --tab1
  --tab2
--table2
  --tab2
  --tab2
```

I am giving a text "tab" and using  `treeViewMenu.SelectedNode = txtbox1.Text`, it selects the very first match (i.e node: table1)

I want all the nodes having "tab" in its name to be selected. (i.e table1 and table2)

I have tried passing an array to `treeViewMenu.SelectedNode =array[]`, but this is not working.

Comment: What did you want to do after they are selected? As the possible duplicate shows the tree view was not designed for multi-select.

Comment: Also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25499249/how-do-i-select-multiple-nodes-at-a-time-from-treeview-control-using-c-sharp-and

Answer (score 0):

A `TreeView` is not designed for `MultiSelect`. But if you only want to see which Nodes match to the string in the `TextBox` you can change the `BackColor` of this `Nodes`.

```
private void txtbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (TreeNode tn in this.treeViewMenu.Nodes)
    {
        SetColor(tn);
    }
}

private void SetColor(TreeNode Node)
{
    if (Node.Text.Contains(this.txtbox1.Text))
    {
        Node.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
        Node.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        Node.Tag = true; //for later to find out which Nodes are "selected"
    }
    else
    {
        Node.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromKnownColor(System.Drawing.KnownColor.Window);
        Node.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromKnownColor(System.Drawing.KnownColor.WindowText);
        Node.Tag = false;
    }

    foreach (TreeNode subNode in Node.Nodes)
    {
        SetColor(subNode);
    }
}
```

To find out which Nodes are "selected" you can use this:

```
private void btn_GetSelected_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedNodes = "";

    foreach (TreeNode tn in this.treeViewMenu.Nodes)
    {
        GetSelectedNodesByTag(tn, ref selectedNodes);
    }
    MessageBox.Show(selectedNodes, "Selected Nodes");
}

private void GetSelectedNodesByTag(TreeNode Node, ref string SelectedNodes)
{
    if ((bool)Node.Tag == true)
    {
        if (SelectedNodes != "") SelectedNodes += "\n";
        SelectedNodes += Node.FullPath;
    }

    foreach (TreeNode subNode in Node.Nodes)
    {
        GetSelectedNodesByTag(subNode, ref SelectedNodes);
    }
}
```

You also could use the `CheckBoxes`-Property to show the selected Nodes:

```
private void SetChecked(TreeNode Node)
{
    if (Node.Text.Contains(this.txtbox1.Text))
    {
        Node.Checked = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Node.Checked = false;
    }

    foreach (TreeNode subNode in Node.Nodes)
    {
        SetChecked(subNode);
    }
}
```

And find out which Nodes are checked:

```
private void GetCheckedNodes(TreeNode Node, ref string SelectedNodes)
{
    if (Node.Checked)
    {
        if (SelectedNodes != "") SelectedNodes += "\n";
        SelectedNodes += Node.FullPath;
    }

    foreach (TreeNode subNode in Node.Nodes)
    {
        GetCheckedNodes(subNode, ref SelectedNodes);
    }
}
```